# Convert a String representation of number to Integer in Java 8+(single line without if)

Tags: string, java-8, integer

This sounds simple, but I can't find a way to convert a `String` value(possibly null) to `Integer` in single line without using `if else` in Java 8+. The answer might involve usage of `ofNullable` and `isPresent`.

Some things I have tried:

```
String x = ...;

Integer.valueOf(x); // fails if x is null
Optional.ofNullable(Integer.valueOf(x)).orElse(null); // NullPointerException
```

Comment: @Oleksandr its not duplicate read carefully

Comment: Nitpick, but a String value can't be null. A String _variable_ can.

Comment: I agree with @Oleksandr there is an answer there that is a duplicate of this

Comment: An answer being a duplicate does not mean the question is a duplicate. [Handling duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/29/handling-duplicate-questions/) (EDIT: Not saying the question is or isn't, just as a comment so we're all on the same page, whether _an answer_ is a duplicate is not a closure criterion.)

Comment: @Amadan agreed, but even the question is a duplicate

Comment: @Eugene question is not duplicate. Other one asks for int not Integer, and related to Java and not Java 8+, and don't have the same constraints(single line, no if else)

Comment: @Caner of course in your opinion it's not a duplicate, my impression is that it is - as such I voted to close it.

Comment: @Caner you need to edit the question to make it clear why you think it's not a duplicate. From my perspective `int` and `Integer` are the same thing.

Comment: I think your question might be suitable for reopening if you clearly specify the problem that `x` might be `null`, instead of requiring people to infer this from the comment _"// NullPointerException"_. But in its current form, it is a duplicate in my opinion (even ignoring the fact that even if you address this, the code will still fail when `x` is not a valid numerical string (and thus throws a `NumberFormatException`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int value = Optional.ofNullable(x).map(Integer::parseInt).orElse(0);
```

This will result in a default value of `0` if the input `String` is `null`.

As an alternative, use:

```
Integer value = Optional.ofNullable(x).map(Integer::valueOf).orElse(null);
```

which will result in `null` if the input `String` is `null`.

Comment: I want null if input is null

Comment: @Caner edited answer

Comment: Surprisingly complicated but it will work!

Answer (score 1):

What about using `?` operator instead of one line `if...else`?

```
Integer value = x != null ? Integer.valueOf(x) : null;
```

Comment: this is still a hidden if/else

Comment: thats a bit cheating because x ? a : b is basically an if

Comment: Yes, but I found this is more simple than `Stream's Optional`. Anyway, you could choose the best solution for your particular problem.

Comment: Depends how you look at it. If your problem is "I need to calculate this in an expression context, so I can't use any statements, like `if`, then this is a viable answer. However, anyone who knows about Optional monads will likely know `?:` is the expression equivalent of the `if` statement, and wouldn't post a question if it was about that in the first place.

Comment: I agree this looks more simple